# Reading data from file to struct using fread

Tags: c

I'm writing a piece of code and a part of it is reading "records" from file to n-length array, n given as an argument. Records in file have constant length(in this case 1024) and contain only numerics, spaces and lower letters. Each record is terminated with \n. I'm using following structure to keep one record:

```
typedef struct{
char rec[1024];
} record;
```

And Code for extracting n of them and storing in n-length array of records is written this way:

```
record * recs=malloc(n*sizeof(record));
size_t read=fread(recs,sizeof(record),(size_t)n,f);
```

When I checked output of this operations it turns out that first element of array recs contains all of the records, second all but first and so on instead of keeping one at each element of array. I'm kind of lost, because i thought that it should store each record in different element of array.
As suggested, I'm also providing code for opening a file and printing elements of array:

```
if((f=fopen(argv[2],"r"))==NULL){
        perror("error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

for(int i=0;i<(int)read;i++){
        printf("record number %d\n %s\n",i,recs[i].rec);
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that writes out the records, and also the code that `fopen`s the file.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've edited my question following your suggestions.

Comment: Change `"r"` to `"rb"` and see if it helps.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've changed it and still, when I'm reading for example records 00440,00441 and 00442, first element of the recs array contains all of them, second contains 00441 and 00442 and third one contains only 00443.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your records `rec` isn't a zero terminated string.

So printing using `%s` shows all records because the printing will just continue until it sees a `'\0'`.

So either make sure to add a zero-termination in each `rec` or use another way of printing than `%s`.

BTW: If there isn't any zero-termination inside `recs` you actually have undefined behavior.

This little program mimics the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct r {
    char c[1];
};

int main(void) {
    int i;
    struct r recs[4] = {{'a'}, {'b'}, {'c'}, {'\0'}};
                                      //       ^^^^^
                                      //       Just to stop printing here
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, recs[i].c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 abc
1 bc
2 c
```

Comment: That's probably the case, thanks a lot for your help. I wouldn't find it out by myself for another few hours.